# Is there a way to create an live CD with apps we pick?

Tags: 16.04, live-cd

I have just read this on wikipedia: "Unlike GNOME, KDE Software Compilation, Xfce, or LXDE, Unity is not a collection of applications but is designed to use existing programs"

Is there a way to create a live CD of Ubuntu that gives the option of choosing what apps (of the existing ones) should get installed?

Comment: I would not bother; do that afterwards and if you need to do this more than once save the commands you use to add/remove software into a script so you can execute the script.

Comment: You can install Ubuntu minimal or if UEFI server version (but no server software). And then install just apps you want. I have followed Rinzwind procedure. Once installed you also can export list of installed apps to install in a new system. http://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages

Comment: @oldfred+Rinzwind hey guys. This is completely new to me. So, I can see that the Ubuntu Minimal is small. So, does that come with the kernel, unity shell and the basic things for the system to run normally? The rest of the user apps I can instal, right?

Comment: Minimal is just enough to boot and connect to Internet. You then add what you want. But it does not have UEFI, gui (Unity), nor many drivers like most Wi-Fi. Server has UEFI, but part of its install is adding all the server software which you do not have to choose.

Comment: @oldfred sounds pretty good. One last question if you dont mind: does it come with a simple graphical interface to choose packages or is it all command based? This is what they say on the website: "The mini iso uses a text-based installer, making the image as compact as possible."

My guess is that it isnt at all graphical then, right?

Comment: Its like the old graphics using terminal/DOS or similar. It is not a gui. When install is done you only have command line, but can install gui of choice or a full desktop environment (but then easier to start with that desktop  installer).